# Catching a click anywhere inside a gtk.Window

Tags: python, events, gtk, click, pygtk

consider the following python code:

```
import gtk

class MainWindow():
    def __init__(self):
        self.window = gtk.Window()
        self.window.show()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main = MainWindow()
    gtk.main()
```

I'd need to catch clicks anywhere inside this gtk.Window().
I haven't found any suitable event (I also tried `button-press-event`, but it doesn't work), what am I missing?

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can pack a `gtk.EventBox` into the window.  In general, whenever you have troubles catching events, check if `gtk.EventBox` solves them.

```
import gtk

class MainWindow():
    def __init__(self):
        self.window = gtk.Window()
        self.box = gtk.EventBox ()
        self.window.add (self.box)
        self.box.add (gtk.Label ('some text'))
        self.window.show_all()

        import sys
        self.box.connect ('button-press-event',
                          lambda widget, event:
                              sys.stdout.write ('%s // %s\n' % (widget, event)))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main = MainWindow()
    gtk.main()
```

Note, however, that event propagation upwards the widget hierarchy will stop if a widget handles event itself.  For instance, a parent of `gtk.Button` won't receive click events from it.

Comment: Thank you doublep; do you know of something able to catch also events handled singularly by children widgets?

Comment: @David Paleino: You could try using `gobject.add_emission_hook` and in your callback re-emit caught signal on parent widget — or on a toplevel right away if that's all you need.  No idea if this will work, but that's what I'd try.

Answer (score 0):

So i have this DrawingArea in Window. And on click i get the callback

```
  self.drawingarea = gtk.DrawingArea()
  self.drawingarea.connect ('button-press-event',self.callback)
  self.drawingarea.set_events(gtk.gdk.EXPOSURE_MASK 
                            | gtk.gdk.LEAVE_NOTIFY_MASK 
                            | gtk.gdk.BUTTON_PRESS_MASK 
                            | gtk.gdk.POINTER_MOTION_MASK 
                            | gtk.gdk.POINTER_MOTION_HINT_MASK )
  self.window.add(self.drawingarea)
```

Filter the left or right button:

```
  def callback(self, widget, event):
    print "clicking... left or right"
    if event.button == 1:
      print 'OK - clicked left '
      #os.system("""wmctrl -s 0""")
    return True
```